# Stored Procedure - Error When Converting Date

Tags: oracle, function, stored-procedures

My stored procedure is failing, I am trying to convert the time stamp to a date.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "USP_CLEAN_FOBTPP" 
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO CLN_FOBTPP
    SELECT PART_PAYMENT_ID,
           ISSUING_SHOP,
           TILL_NUMBER,
           SLIP_NUMBER,
           FOBT_NUMBER,
           WHO_PAID,
           to_date(WHEN_PAID,'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),
           AMOUNT_LEFT_TO_PAY,
           FOBT_VALUE,
           STATUS
      FROM IMPORTDB.IMP_FOBTPP;
   COMMIT;
END;
```

The is the error I get:

> ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input
>   string.

This is the format of the `When_Paid` date column

```
11-OCT-17 13.29.20.000000000
11-OCT-17 13.30.21.000000000
11-OCT-17 13.31.11.000000000
11-OCT-17 12.56.39.000000000
11-OCT-17 12.57.28.000000000
11-OCT-17 12.57.46.000000000
```

What is going wrong?

```
Source Table IMPORTDB.IMP_FOBT
Name               Null? Type         
------------------ ----- ------------ 
PART_PAYMENT_ID          NUMBER(38)   
ISSUING_SHOP             CHAR(4)      
TILL_NUMBER              NUMBER(3)    
SLIP_NUMBER              NUMBER(38)   
FOBT_NUMBER              VARCHAR2(30) 
WHO_PAID                 CHAR(20)     
WHEN_PAID                TIMESTAMP(6) 
AMOUNT_LEFT_TO_PAY       NUMBER(19,4) 
FOBT_VALUE               NUMBER(19,4) 
STATUS                   CHAR(2)      

Destination Table IMPORTDB.CLN_FOBTPP
Name               Null?    Type         
------------------ -------- ------------ 
PART_PAYMENT_ID    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(4)  
ISSUING_SHOP       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(4)  
TILL_NUMBER        NOT NULL NUMBER(3)    
SLIP_NUMBER        NOT NULL VARCHAR2(4)  
FOBT_NUMBER        NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30) 
WHO_PAID           NOT NULL CHAR(20)     
WHEN_PAID          NOT NULL DATE         
AMOUNT_LEFT_TO_PAY NOT NULL NUMBER(19,4) 
FOBT_VALUE         NOT NULL NUMBER(19,4) 
STATUS             NOT NULL CHAR(2)
```

This is the table structure.

Comment: what is the data type of `WHEN_PAID` column? If it's `date`(seems this way) then leave it, do not apply `to_date()` function, otherwise it does though double conversion: `date -> character -> back to date`.  In this case values of various NLS parameters come into play `NLS_DATE_FORMAT, NLS_LANGUGAE, NLS_TERRITORY`

Comment: the data type of When_Paid is Timestamp in the source table, and date in the table i want to load the data to.

Comment: I have included the table definitions.

Comment: what a coincidence.!  I just heard a colleague  reach home late as he was stuck resolving this same ORA error

Comment: haha, i'm new with PL-SQL and oracle, but this has left me quite baffled as to what to attempt next.

Comment: Kaushik, any ideas what the fix was that your colleague used?

Comment: You are trying to convert a timestamp to date , which is not necessary. try to insert directly

Comment: If I just leave it the output looks like so: 11-OCT-17, I want the hours minutes and seconds included also.

Comment: No your output depends on your NLS_DATE settings. Check what is saved in your table. do a `TO_CHAR(d,fmt)`

Comment: "The output"? You are inserting into a table. Do you mean, AFTER the insert is done, you are SELECTing from the target table, and you don't see the date in the desired format? What are you using - Toad? SQL Developer? Each has settings to DISPLAY dates; a date is not STORED as a string, like '11-OCT-17', that is only a matter of how it is DISPLAYED.

Answer (score 1):

If the stored data is in `timestamp` data type, what you need is a `CAST`, not `TO_DATE`:

```
...
, cast (when_paid as date) , ...
```

**EDIT**: In a Comment below this Answer, the OP says he is getting an error about the hour having to be between 1 and 12. Not sure what the OP is doing wrong; to prove that is NOT the case for the `cast` function in Oracle, here is an illustration:

```
with input (ts) as (
  select to_timestamp('11-OCT-17 15:35:24.000000000', 'dd-MON-rr hh24:mi:ss.ff')
  from   dual
)
select ts, cast(ts as date) as dt
from   input;

TS                            DT
----------------------------  -------------------
11-OCT-17 15.35.24.000000000  2017-10-11 15:35:24
```

Comment: So is the cast function what I should be using?

Comment: cast (WHEN_PAID as date), I am left with ORA-01849: hour must be between 1 and 12

Comment: @J.Doe - I am not there to look over your shoulder to see what you are doing. I just edited the answer to show that `cast` has no issue with hours greater than 12. You are not sharing exactly what you are doing, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert a `TIMESTAMP` column with `TO_DATE` to insert into a `DATE` column - which is not necessary. This works perfectly.

```
create table source1 ( t TIMESTAMP );

create table dest1 ( t DATE );
INSERT INTO source1 VALUES(SYSTIMESTAMP);

INSERT INTO dest1 SELECT * FROM source1;
```

**PS:** change this line `to_date(WHEN_PAID,'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')` to `WHEN_PAID,`

Comment: This looks good but how do I amend my stored procedure to include this?

Comment: Also, always Include an `INTO` clause with all the columns in same  order as `select` to avoid confusion

Comment: That is a poor practice though. If you input a timestamp and output a date, Oracle will do the conversion for you implicitly, but it is best if you code these conversions explicitly.

Comment: create or replace PROCEDURE                                                "USP_CLEAN_FOBTPP" 
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO CLN_FOBTPP
  SELECT PART_PAYMENT_ID,
  ISSUING_SHOP,
  TILL_NUMBER,
  SLIP_NUMBER,
  FOBT_NUMBER,
  WHO_PAID,
  WHEN_PAID,
  AMOUNT_LEFT_TO_PAY,
  FOBT_VALUE,
  STATUS
  FROM IMPORTDB.IMP_FOBTPP;
  COMMIT;
END;

Comment: 11/10/2017
11/10/2017
11/10/2017
11/10/2017
11/10/2017
11/10/2017
11/10/2017
11/10/2017
11/10/2017
11/10/2017
11/10/2017
11/10/2017

Comment: My lack of knowledge around this is really hurting me, i remove the conversion and i'm still missing the HH:MM:SS that i require.

Comment: where are you missing it?  It gets stored in the table. It does not appear when you do `select column_name from table` .After you've  inserted , do a `select TO_CHAR(WHEN_PAID, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS')  FROM your_dest_table`

Comment: Yes this works, so the data was stored in the table, but a standard select didn't show the records.